# Unable to authenticate using WSFederation after upgrading to .NET 5 from .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, nginx, .net-5

I've recently converted my project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5. Everything is working except the ability for users to sign in when the authentication is passing through a reverse proxy.

When the users are connected to the VPN, everything works, but off the VPN, they get a 404 after signing into ADFS when trying to POST to /signin-wsfed.

I've added this to my Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
        options.ForwardLimit = null;
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
}
```

I've turned on some header debugging as prescribed in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#forwarded-headers-middleware-options

I noticed that the X-Forwarded-For value when not using the UserForwardedHeaders is not equal to the X-Original-For when I have it turned on, the link suggests they should be the same.

NGINX is our reverse proxy, here is some of the config:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://redacted_ip_address/;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-Queue-Start "t=${msec}000";
    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;
    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    client_max_body_size       50m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions of something I could try, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that .NET Core stores more information in the authentication Cookie and that was causing the size of the cookie to exceed that of the Nginx configuration.